# How to Upgrade Oracle VirtualBox 4.1.12 to to 4.2.10

Tags: virtualbox

I installed Oracle VirtualBox 4.1.12 in my Ubuntu 12.04.

Now I want upgrade from 4.1.12 to 4.2.10 version.

How can I upgrade the Oracle VirtualBox in command line

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

Add this line to `/etc/apt/sources.list`:

```
deb http://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/debian precise contrib
```

Add PGP keyring:

```
wget -q http://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/debian/oracle_vbox.asc -O- \
| sudo apt-key add -
```

Update source list:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

Then install `virtualbox-4.2`:

```
sudo apt-get install virtualbox-4.2
```

Comment: ok but already i installed 4.1.12 version.. if i install 4.2 it will get any problem or not

Comment: You can remove 4.1.12 before install 4.2

Comment: ok but i created 4 to 5 vm's in the virtual box.. if i remove the virtualbox any impact on those vm's

Comment: I think they will run normally. However, you should export those machines to ovf to backup before doing anything.